# Firebase database cloud function on delete event

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I want to run a cloud function after a value is removed from some table.
I looked at the documentation (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events), but didn't find anything related to my issues.

Does Cloud Functions for Firebase support such a thing?

Comment: *firebaser here* John's answer will functionally get you what you want. But it invokes the function for every write, which means you're also paying for writes that you're not interested in. We've heard the request to trigger on more specific types of write operations from many developers and may add support for those in a future release.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use something like following:

```
exports.yourDeleteFunction = functions.database.ref(<your_ref>).onWrite(function (event) {

  // Exit if record still exists
  if (event.data.exists()) {
    return;
  }

  // Your code to handle delete

});
```

Comment: Looks like latest version of `firebase-functions` now has more granular control for things like this - https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/releases/tag/v0.5.9